# Does function written in sql inherit IMMUTABLE or PARALLEL SAFE automatically in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

For example, if I write

```
create function foo(int x)
RETURNS int 
AS xxxxx
language 'c' IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

and

```
create function bar(int x)
RETURNS int
AS 'select foo(x)'
language 'sql';
```

Would `bar()` be treated as immutable and parallel safe when performing queries?

Answer (score 2):

No, the function will not "inherit" any attributes from the called function.

You will have to specify those options when creating the function `bar()`.

---

Btw: the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes. Support for that is deprecated and might break in a future version.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions   I find this introduction and to my understanding it's indicating oppsite result?

Comment: @Bobi.Liu: look at the pre-conditions for inlining. You either have to define the function as `immutable` or `stable`. If you leave it out, it defaults to `volatile` which will prevent inlining

Comment: I think the line "if the function is declared IMMUTABLE, then the expression must not invoke any non-immutable function or operator" indicates that it don't have to immutable to be inlined?

Comment: It must be _declared_ immutable. The optimizer does not inspect the contents of a function (and definitely not any called function), it only checks the declaration.